# Can't get data of authenticated path - Springboot JWT Auth

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I have a basic demo of JWT Auth, In which I am able to register, login (generate token) and authenticate corretly, but once I add the token in postman, I only get an Ok status, but cant get any data from my controller

```
`@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String>  getHome(){

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello world");


        //return userService.getUsers();
    }`
```

It does work if I remove the authentication from the path and add .permitAll():

```
`http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
     .authorizeHttpRequests(rq -> {
                        rq.requestMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll();
                        rq.requestMatchers("/home/**").permitAll(); 
                        rq.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    });`
```

Thanks!

I tried adding "rq.requestMatchers("/home/**").permitAll();", and the restcontroller does work, but only without authentication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can check what type of token is selected in postmant under Authorization tab, maybe it will work with other types like OAuth 2.0 etc.

Second, make sure you have a filter like JwtRequestFilter in your application to intercept incoming requests, extract the JWT token, and set up Spring Security's authentication context based on that token. If you not sure, place brakepoint in your inteceptor and check if security recognizing this token

Also you can try add wildcard "/" and check if it works without specific marchers:

```
http
.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // Allow all requests
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
);
```